# Getting FileNotFoundException on a few URLs. Trying to download

Tags: java, android, file, download, inputstream

I'm developing a download-everything app for Android devices, and just a few URLs are giving me problems by throwing FileNotFoundException for some reason. I print out the URL and copy it to my browser and it works fine there, so I dont know what the problem is.

Exception:

```
W/System.err(14261): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/BillBurr/~5/pCkxUgHf5tY/MMPC_9-9-12.mp3
```

Code (minus most exception handling):

```
URL u = new URL(uri);

HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();
c.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);

int totalSize = c.getContentLength();
InputStream in = null;
try {
     in = c.getInputStream(); // Exception problem here 

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int len1 = 0;
     ................
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the file was not found... I just tried to download it. It's not there.

Comment: Please, read this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: ``c.setDoOutput(true)`` seems to cause problems and I think you shouldn't set the flag at all.

Comment: yes, it's as simple as that. Thanks harism!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `c.setDoOutput(true);`.  DOh!

Cheers harism.